# ko.applyBindings gives error "ko is not defined" when using ko in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I have the following in my MVC Layout (at the bottom):

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/viewmodels")
```

I see knockout loading in my Sources tab in Developer tools.

In one of my views, I have to do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">ko.applyBindings(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));</script>
```

But this gives me an error: `ko is not defined`

Why is this happening, despite knockout being loaded?

Comment: are you using an AMD loader like require.js somewhere in your app?

Comment: no I'm not... I just have the Render in my Layout and then a reference to ko in a view.

Comment: can you post what the "view source" output looks like?

Comment: I'm sorry... I just moved the Render(knockout) to the top of my layout page and it began working.  I'm now running into a different issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840173/knockout-mvc-you-cannot-apply-bindings-multiple-times-to-the-same-element

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was that my view was loading before knockout.  Pushing this up to the top of my Layout.cshtml:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
```

Fixed the problem.

Comment: Since you are using jquery, you can leverage Jquery's ondom ready function and add ko references and binding inside it. This way even if you need to keep references below the view (which is a good idea for performance reasons), javascript parser will not complain.

Comment: @Yogesh Could you perhaps provide a sample of how that would be done?  I'm also a bit of a noob with knockout and client-side scripting

Answer (score 2):

you should put **@ko.Apply(Model)** at bottom of page too, instead of pull scripts on top of page.

The following code will solve your problem

```
@section scripts{
    @ko.Apply(Model)
}
```

Remember to declare a **scripts** section on layout view, otherwise will cause a exception

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Answer (score 1):

In My scenario [@RobVious answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18840192/2940265) was part but not completed. I followed these steps to the solution.

1. Add below sections into header `<head>` of shared layout (ex **_Layout.cshtml**)

   `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")`
2. Then Add knockout code to document ready tag like below.

   `$(document).ready(function () {
           function AppViewModel() {
               this.firstName = "Bert";
               this.lastName = "Bertington";
           }
           ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
       });`
3. if this won't work check whether you **knockout.js** is loading or not like below using inspect elements
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by removing my script line at the end of my Index.cshtml file:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/ConfigGroup.js"></script>
```

and replacing it with:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/ConfigGroup.js")
}
```

I guess section Scripts gets loaded at a different time than  includes.

now my reference to ko.  in ConfigGroup.js script no longer has errors